# EF Performance - update cost via repository

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, repository

I have a question about performance of EF when it updates data via repository. For example I have UOW concentrated on orders. When I want to update a row, it specifically sets the specific part of the row and commits it to db.

Well at this part, does EF transports all the table back to db or it just updates by id and sends only the necessary data? In my opinion, it doesn't mean to transport all table when you save a change in the table with update. Hope it sounds clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EF is capable of doing Update Set.  It will only update the changed entity fields.
Run SQL profiler and you will see that.